# How to disable a UITableView from scrolling up vertically?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview, uitableview

I'm using `EGORefreshTableHeader` in conjunction with a static cell (defined in a nib) in a UITableView.

I'd like to be able to scroll the tableview down to trigger the `EGORefreshTableHeader` and thus refresh the data in the static cell. BUT, as the static cell is sized to fit perfectly in the window, I want to prevent folks from being able to scroll up.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGFloat a;

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    a = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > a) 
    {
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, a)];
    }
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I was thinking of doing something similar hoping there was a simple setting. But as that doesn't seem to be the case ... this works great with the exception the "if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=a)" should be "if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > a).  Thanks

Comment: sorry, i have mistaken the direction, haha. thank you for accept my answer, this is my first. happy coding.