# UITableView Only Scroll Down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I want to configure a `UITableView` so that it can only scroll down. In other words, disable the table view from scrolling upward. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable a UITableView from scrolling up vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935856/how-to-disable-a-uitableview-from-scrolling-up-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

### Details

- Xcode 14.2
- Swift  5.7.2

### Solution

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    private var previousContentOffset = CGPoint()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.tableView = tableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = .gray
    }
}

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView === tableView {
            if previousContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
                scrollView.contentOffset.y = previousContentOffset.y
            }
            previousContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
}

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 1000 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return cell
    }
}
```